# Global variable declaration in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt4, qtnetwork

I have made a Gui thread and a QTcpSocket thread in Qt.I want to access data
 
from QTcpSocket thread to Gui thread.How to solve it?
Do i need  to declare some global variable and how?

Comment: You mentioned that the answers helped you. Can you please mark the most helpful answer as accepted, to help subsequent visitors to follow the discussion? You can accept an answer by clicking the outlined  mark right below the voting buttons at the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to communicate via signal-slot connections. There is one QObject in each thread. The sending object has a signal, which is connected to the slot of the receiving object in the other thread.

In this setup, you make sure that the objects on both ends of the connections are configured to live in the correct threads. You might need to call `QObject::moveToThread()`. QObject also has a property where you can get the current thread (for debugging purposes in this case).

Then just establish the signal-slot connection as usual. Since both objects are in different threads, when the signal is triggered, a slot invocation event will be placed in the event loop of the receiving flag. This is explained in the Qt documentation, look for `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

The QTcpSocket is created from the gui thread.
So at that point the gui thread has a pointer to the socket object.
It then creates a connection between a slot in the gui and a signal in the socket.
In the socket object whenever you get data you simply emit a signal containing the data, which will be picked up by the gui thread.

You can pass any Qt type eg QString, QByteArray (or a raw pointer), through a signal/slot very efficiently. The details if signals between threads are also handled automatically.